# Berlekamp's algorithm over $Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Using the algorithm of Berlekamp decomposed into irreducible factors polynomials:
 $(1)\ \  x^5 + 3x^3 + 2x + 1$ over $Z_3$ and
 $(2)\ \  x^4 + 2x + 1$ over $k$, $|k|=4$

Comment: What do you mean by over $k$ with |k|=4? If you mean characteristic 2 then the polynomial is just 1!

Comment: @almagest No, the polynomial is $x^4+2x+1=x^4+1=(x+1)^4$. the 2. stands for the second polynomial.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Crazy formatting.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks a lot for your answer!But how i have to solve this exercise by algorithm of Berlekamps:(Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Berlekamps algorithm here (but you can use it, of course).
The first polynomial is given by
$$
x^5+2x+1,
$$
because $3=0$, hence $3x^3=0$. It is easily seen to be irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$. The second polynomial is
$$
x^4+2x+1=x^4+1=(x+1)^4
$$
over all fields of characteristic $2$, hence over $k$. Also here you do not need Berlekamp's algorithm; it just follows from the formula $(x+1)^2=x^2+1$ over characteristic $2$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!But how i have to solve this exercise by algorithm of Berlekamps:(Could you help me with that?

Comment: Berlekamp's algorithm has a squarefree polynomial as input. So the input would be $x+1$ to Berlekamp in the second case. I am sure you can do this yourself now.